# how to drain a specific heating zone?

Tags: zoned-heating

I have hot water baseboard heating, with three zones. I would like to drain one of them in order to complete some renovations which requires moving some baseboard out of the way.

I'm not sure what the sequence here should be... what should be turned off, and on in what order. I know which valve corresponds with which zone; in the pictures, it's the middle one with the yellow handles. And, I believe the white handle valve is the boiler return.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Some pics here for reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JYQH.jpg

Comment: It's exceedingly rare for zones to be setup/valved for complete isolation, so you'll probably need to drain them all.

Comment: Two zones serve the house, and one goes to the hot water tank. Does that make a difference in needing to drain them all? I'd be fine doing that, but I don't know in what sequence to turn everything off/on.

Comment: what makes a difference is where the shut off and drain valves are.  I can't see that from here.

Comment: All the valves are shown here, if it helps: https://i.imgur.com/LLRcA2a_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium